# Justified and vertically centered header elements not working with fixed header

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

I found a really [interesting article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/14/justified-and-vertically-centered-header-elements/comment-page-3/#comments) on how to VAlign elements inside a Header. The thing is I need a fixed header with a 100% height (so i can make the VAlign work properly). Since the Header is out of the document flow the 100% Height is making the header take whe whole viewport height. Is there any way to make this method work using a fixed header with a 100% height but avoiding the header to take the 100% height of the viewport ?

here's the code and a codepen link :

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwWbKP)

```css
#banner {
  background: #3677ae;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 2%;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: justify;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
#banner:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
#banner #logo,
#banner nav.navAplicacio {
  display: inline-block;
}
#banner #logo h1 {
  line-height: normal;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
#banner #logo h1:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
#banner #logo h1 img {
  height: 13px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  width: 77px;
}
#banner .navAplicacio {
  line-height: normal;
}
#banner .navAplicacio ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#banner .navAplicacio ul li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 11px;
}
#banner .navAplicacio ul li:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
#banner .navAplicacio ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header id="banner" role="banner">
  <div id="logo">
    <h1 class="site-title">
   <img alt="${logo_description}" height="13px" src="${images_folder}/EACAT.png" width="77px" />
 </h1>
  </div>
  <nav class="navAplicacio">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Bloc</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Suport</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://logout.gat">Surt</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://dev.lala.cat">Torna</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="btn-usuari" type="button" id="dropUsuari">Jordi Parodi <i>(Martorelles, Aj. de)</i>  <span class="ico"><img src="${images_folder}/EC80017.JPG" alt="Escut Aj. de Martorelles"></span><span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: What's wrong with using   **height: 20vh;**? Tried it there and seems fine?

Comment: @Girgio it thought it was obvious i guess is not. I'm including the question now, thanks !

Comment: @jbutler483 unfortunately i need support for IE8 and also vh is just partially supported in IE9. Also i don't know what else did you change but just changing the header height is not working for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emvbKW

Comment: HAve been working around this and can't find any solution. Any ideas would really help guys.